# I need a dropdown in a table to update some data from PHP to mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I have a MySql query with some left outer join tables and a php table that willedit and update the MySql table
I have some text input for fields that belong to the table that I am editing. I also have some text inputs that are readonly for now because they are foreign keys in the MySql table but I need to see them as text in the php table to be able to know the data. What I want is to be able to edit those fields in the php table as well and to do that I need dropdowns instead of text inputs :
    1- They need to default the current data and I want to be able to select from the dropdown to change the current data to a different one. If need it
    *the default should come from the table that I am going to update but the selection option should come from the foreign table 
    2- And I need to pass that selection as a foreign key (integer) to be able to update the MySql table

```
 <body>

    <!-- this is my table header-->        
        <table>
    <thead>
    <tr>

                <th>Transaction Category</th>
                <th>Transaction Group</th>

                <th>Transaction Name</th>
                <th>Amount</th>
                <th>Date from</th>
                <th>Date to</th>
                <th>Notes</th>



        </tr></thead>


        <?php



 //this is my form/Table      
if (mysqli_num_rows($result2) > 0 ){


        while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result2)){
 echo '<tr><form method="post">';



        echo  '<td><input type="text" name="transCat['.$row["budgetEstimatedId"].']" value="'.$row["transCat"].'" readonly="readonly"></td>';


       echo  '<td><input type="text" name="transGroup['.$row["budgetEstimatedId"].']" value="'.$row["transGroup"].'" readonly="readonly"></td>';
        echo '<td><select name="transGroup['.$row["budgetEstimatedId"].']" >'; 
                while($row1 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result3)){ 
               echo '<option value='.$row1["transGroupsId"].'" if('.$row1["transGroup"].'=='.$row1["transGroupsId"].' selected="selected")>'.$row1['transGroup'].'</option>';
                   }
              echo '</select></td>';
        echo  '<td><input type="text" name="transNames['.$row["budgetEstimatedId"].']" value="'.$row["transNames"].'" readonly="readonly"></td>';

         echo  '<td><input type="decimal" name="amount['.$row["budgetEstimatedId"].']" value="'.$row["amount"].'"> </td>';

            echo  '<td><input type="date" name="dateFrom['.$row["budgetEstimatedId"].']" value="'.$row["dateFrom"].'"></td>';

            echo  '<td><input type="date" name="dateTo['.$row["budgetEstimatedId"].']" value="'.$row["dateTo"].'"> </td>';

            echo  '<td><textarea name="notes['.$row["budgetEstimatedId"].']"cols=34 rows=2 wrap=soft>'.$row["notes"].'</textarea> </td>';



         echo   '<td><input type="hidden" name="budgetEstimatedId[]" value="'.$row["budgetEstimatedId"].'"></td>';

        }   

    echo '<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Multiple CHANGE">';
        echo '<td><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Multiple CHANGE">';
    echo '</form></tr>';

        }

    ?>


        </table>    

 </body>
    <?php
       //this is where the insert start
if(isset($_POST["submit"]))
    {

foreach($_POST["budgetEstimatedId"] AS $budgetEstimatedIdID){
    $amountID = $_POST["amount"][$budgetEstimatedIdID];
$dateFromID = $_POST["dateFrom"][$budgetEstimatedIdID];
$dateToID = $_POST["dateTo"][$budgetEstimatedIdID];
$notesID = $_POST["notes"][$budgetEstimatedIdID];





$update = "UPDATE budgetestimated SET amount='$amountID', dateFrom='$dateFromID', dateTo='$dateToID', notes='$notesID' WHERE budgetEstimatedId='$budgetEstimatedIdID' LIMIT 1";
    mysqli_query($con, $update) or die (mysqli_error());
    }

    }
?>
```

Comment: Do you plan to implement it solely in PHP?

Comment: yes, that is my plan and what I would prefer.

Comment: do you know if that is possible with solely Php?

Comment: It is possible, but not recommended, since you'll have to POST your changes each time you change something, then wait for PHP to process your request and send you the updated page.

Comment: what is recommended?, what would be the best way to do it? Thanks

Comment: I was trying to do it in PHP because that is what I am learning, but if there is a better way, I am interested. If you show me a code that will do it in another language I will do it. thanks